# Type interface org.hibernate.validator.method.MethodValidator not supported for unwrapping

Tags: validation, jboss, wildfly, bean-validation, wildfly-8

I'm using JSR 303 Bean validation on my RestEasy endpoints:

```
@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ValidateRequest
public class RecipeEndpoint
{
    //more code

    @GET
    @Path("/get/{accessId}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response getByAccessId(@PathParam("accessId") @NotEmpty String accessId) throws InternalServerErrorException
    {
        RecipeBo result = recipeService.getByAccessId(accessId, userId);

        return Response.ok().entity(result).build();
    }
}
```

when I startup Wildfly 8.2.0.Final I get the following exception:

```
18:14:36,035 WARN  [org.jboss.as.weld] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS016018: Using deployment classloader to load proxy classes for module org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-validator-provider-11:main. Package-private access will not work. To fix this the module should declare dependencies on [org.jboss.weld.core, org.jboss.weld.spi]
18:14:36,232 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class com.mysite.myapp.domain.JaxRsActivator
18:14:36,291 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.validation.hibernate.AbstractValidatorContextResolver] (MSC service thread 1-1) Unable to load Validation support: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000036: Type interface org.hibernate.validator.method.MethodValidator not supported for unwrapping.
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.unwrap(ValidatorImpl.java:336) [hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.validation.hibernate.AbstractValidatorContextResolver.getGeneralValidator(AbstractValidatorContextResolver.java:47) [resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider-3.0.11.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.validation.hibernate.AbstractValidatorContextResolver.getContext(AbstractValidatorContextResolver.java:54) [resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider-3.0.11.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.validation.hibernate.ValidatorContextResolver.getContext(ValidatorContextResolver.java:16) [resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider-3.0.11.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.validation.hibernate.ValidatorContextResolver$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getContext(Unknown Source) [resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider-3.0.11.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory$1.getContext(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2190) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.<init>(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:118) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.processMethod(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:280) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.register(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:251) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:221) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:193) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:179) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:156) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addPerRequestResource(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:75) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registration(ResteasyDeployment.java:400) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:241) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:112) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:220) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:125) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:508) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:88)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
```

At first I though it depends on the first WARN and found this entry:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3812
I checked the solution but in `/opt/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/picketlink/core/main/module.xml` there are these dependencies:

```
<module name="org.jboss.weld.core"/>
<module name="org.jboss.weld.spi"/>
```

Maybe it has no effect or it does not even affect the validation WARN:

```
Type interface org.hibernate.validator.method.MethodValidator not supported for unwrapping.
```

I didn't add any own implementations of any Validator. Do I miss anything here to get bean validation to work?

Comment: Validation of methods is now done by default.  You shouldn't need @ValidateRequest on your class.  Try removing it and seeing if that fixes the issue.

Comment: @JohnAment If I remove it, I get the same errors, so no difference.

Comment: In this version of Wildfly Bean Validation 1.1 (JSR 349) is provided and not Bean Validation 1.0 (JSR 303). Are you trying to add dependencies for the latter? This would cause class loading problems and potentially the problem you see, since the MethodValidator is not part of Bean Validation 1.0. You need to provide more context though (pom.xml, structure and content of deployed artifact, etc) to get more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really smells like a classloading issue. You should make sure you **do not** package any of the provided EE dependencies in your war/ear archive (resteasy-hibernatevalidator, hibernate-*, weld-*).

Comment: You were right. I forgot to add the "provided" scope to the Maven dependency, so it was packed into the war.

Answer (score 0):

@ValidateRequest is not part of JSR 303 this was an annotation used as part of Bean Validation 1.0.

Make sure you are only using bean validation 1.1 tags and you should be okay.

Comment: If I remove @ValidateRequest, I get the same error message.

Comment: please post your entire code. what is the import for NotEmpty?

Comment: It's `import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;` but when I change everything to @NotNull, I get the same errors, so no change.